# Flex mobile list won't scroll vertically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile

In flex 4.6, mobile project, i have a list component with a custom itemRenderer. My problem is that the list won't scroll on vertical. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong.
Here is the code :

```
<s:List left="0" right="0" top="0" dataProvider="{DataModel.instance.listaRestaurante}" 
itemRenderer="itemRenderers.restauranteRender" width="320" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"      verticalScrollPolicy="on">
<s:layout>
<s:VerticalLayout gap="10" requestedRowCount="-1" useVirtualLayout="true" />        
</s:layout>
</s:List>
```

Thank you

SOLVED by putting buttom="0" on list

Comment: Are you sure there are enough items in your list for scrolling to be needed?  -1 strikes me as a weird value for requestedRowCount.  I wonder if that is causing issues.

Comment: Hmm, I have enough items . If i put requestedRowCount="10" the list scroll but not showing all items. I if i remove the requestedRowCount the list won't scroll again

Comment: Solved - the solution was to put bottom="0" on list

Answer (score 1):

> SOLVED by putting buttom="0" on list

Do you know why this solved the problem? I guess not, so here goes:

Originally, you hadn't assigned a height to the list. Because of this, the list would expand indefinitely until it accomodated all the objects.

When you assigned a height (setting bottom=0 is effetively the same thing, just assigning a relative height), the list was constrained to that height. Any objects overflowing would cause a scrollbar to be shown.